# How can I see the side of a cube near the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, observers

I've been learning special relativity and met such a statement that says an observer can see the side of objects when he travels near the speed of light. Here is the original diagram.

[image]

I read some material from https://www.spacetimetravel.org/tompkins/node3.html and https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/course/8/8.20/www/m44.pdf. But they didn't answer my question. Take the cube in my diagram for example, **when it's the observer moving, how can the light from C make a way to O?** I know due to relativity we can always have the cube moving and observer at rest, but how to explain the effect if we take the frame of the cube?

Comment: Just a note if you want to search more about that, that the technical name is [Terrell rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrell_rotation). (Sometimes Terrell-Penrose, Penrose-Terrell, or Lampa-Terrell-Penrose rotation). The wikipedia article I linked has some nice visualizations and pointers to other sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the frame of the cube, **O** is just sweeping out photons that have already been sent towards places **O** is going to be. No special relativity is required. Suppose we have a house on a giant turntable and we turn it as a car drives past so that the front door always directly faces the car. Unruly children in the house throw rocks at the car from the windows. The children on the side of the house facing the direction that the car is going can throw rocks at the car by throwing rocks where the car is going to be, even though the car never enters their field of fire. The passing car is continuously barraged by rocks from two faces of the house. Use massless rocks traveling at $c$, an improbably fast car, and an unreasonably large number of very tiny children, and you have the effect described in the diagram (once we switch back to **O**'s frame, including correcting for relativity of simultaneity).

Comment: Take the house example, but now the house is fixed and won't constantly turn the front to the car. So in such circumstance, if the car stop before it cross the side line of house, it won't be hit by the rock, right? 
<br>
I mean, back to the pic, if a picture is taken before the observer cross the CB line, will he be able to see the CB side?

Comment: @KakaG If we're having the observer take a picture, we're switching back to the observer's rest frame, in which the cube is continuously moving out of the way of light reflected from the CB side. The line CB is the line defined by where C is "right now" and where B is "right now". B and C are in different places, so different frames measure different times between events at B and C, hence different lines CB.

Comment: Last question, if there's another observer staying at point C, will the moving observer and he oberve each other at the same time?(let go of relativity, if consider Terrell effect alone)

Comment: Events in different places like "O observes C" and "C observes O" being simultaneous isn't physically meaningful. However: both frames will agree that O observed C at the same time as O sent the first message from O that C eventually received. "O observes C" and "O immediately transmits 'I see C!" are events in the same place, therefore different frames agree that they were simultaneous.